# CellInfo api isRegistered() always return false

Tags: android, api

In the below code isRegistered() method always return false though the SIM is registered with the network. Permissions used "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" on API 17

```
List<CellInfo> cellinoflist= tm.getAllCellInfo();
for(CellInfo cellinfo : cellinoflist)
{
  if(cellinfo!=null && cellinfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
    CellInfoGsm GSMinfo = (CellInfoGsm) cellinfo;
    Log.d(TAG, "GSM network registered: "+GSMinfo.isRegistered());
  }
}
```

Is the any other means we could get the this working.

Comment: Where does the variable 'cellinfo' come from?

Comment: updated  missing code

Comment: anyone here? any pointers to proceed

Comment: a) I'm assuming you're getting tm from Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)?

Comment: I'm using TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); in activity.

Comment: logcat report '06-26 10:36:17.468: D/cellinfo_acitivty(5079):  cellinfo CellInfoGsm: mRegistered=NO mTimeStampType=unknown mTimeStamp=9223372036854775807ns, GsmCellIdentitiy:android.telephony.CellIdentityGsm@7fffff65 mMcc=2147483647 mMnc=2147483647 mLac=2147483647 mCid=2147483647 mPsc=2147483647, CellSignalStrengthGsm: ss=2147483647 ber=2147483647'

Comment: Unable to import "CellInfo" package, its giving error "Unable to resolve CellInfo" after integrating the above mention code.Can you please let me know how it is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow for me this seems to work for SIM cards registered with 4G network. I could see the isRegistered() return true for the first time. But the CellSignalStrengthLte values are same for all variables(rsrp,rsrq,rssnr,cqi,ta)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the "ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
```

Comment: yes,I used both ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION but not difference in the output.

Comment: Somehow  for me this seems to work for SIM cards registered with 4G network. I could see the isRegistered() return true for the first time. But the CellSignalStrengthLte values are same for all variables(rsrp,rsrq,rssnr,cqi,ta)